# How to target multiple applications from same overlay package?

Tags: android, overlay, rro

I have a Runtime Resource Overlay(RRO) package with manifest as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application android:hasCode="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.Fluid.Dark"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="29"
        android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>

    <overlay
        android:targetPackage="com.amazon.firelauncher"
        android:targetName="CarUiCodelab"
        android:isStatic="true"
        android:priority="1"
        android:resourcesMap="@xml/sample_overlay"
        />
</manifest>
```

Need some guidance to see how i can do the same?

I tried doing the same by adding one more  tag however that didn't worked. Manifest example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application android:hasCode="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.Fluid.Dark"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="29"
        android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>

    <overlay
        android:targetPackage="com.amazon.firelauncher"
        android:targetName="CarUiCodelab"
        android:isStatic="true"
        android:priority="1"
        android:resourcesMap="@xml/sample_overlay"
        />
    <overlay
        android:targetPackage="com.android.settings"
        android:targetName="CarUiCodelab1"
        android:isStatic="true"
        android:priority="1"
        android:resourcesMap="@xml/sample_overlay"
        />
</manifest>
```

My aim is use the same RRO package to target multiple other apps too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as of today.
You will have to create another RRO package to overlay the second target.